# Using a single webview for multiple fragments in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview

I'm creating an Android application with a tabbed interface. There are 5 tabs. Three are controlled by the native activity while the other two load an Angular application at the route to show its content. For example, tapping the Dashboard tab loads the Angular app at `/dashboard`.

So far, I have each tab referencing its own `webview`. This presents two problems.

1. The Angular application is parsed every time one of the tabs is tapped.
2. The result is a webview for every tap. I.e. back and forth twice produces 4 webviews, which is confirmable when the app is inspected via `chrome://inspect`.

   ```
   public class DashboardFragment extends Fragment {

   private DashboardViewModel dashboardViewModel;

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       dashboardViewModel =
               ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(DashboardViewModel.class);
       View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard, container, false);

       final WebView webView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_dashboard);
       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
       webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
       webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
       webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

       webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html#dashboard");

       return root;
   }
   }
   ```

Is there a way to use a single webview that persists across both tabs and without reparsing the JS every time?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

But you can preserve your `DashboardFragment`(do not recreate your tab each time it clicks).

There are multiple ways to do that, for example, hide/show the fragment whenever exit/enter. Or if you're using Navigation Component you can preserve your tab somehow.